# Display in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

How can I use `display()` instead of `print()` in python VS Code? I wanted to plot a more stylish table, instead of print, but I can do `display()` only in Jupyter

Comment: my advice would be to run the notebook in VS Code

Comment: Have you [read the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks)?

Comment: @PaulH I can't use this function in VS code itself without having to resort to Jupyter?

Comment: My guess is "no" since the `display` function is defined by libraries in the Jupyter ecosystem. Plain python scripting isn't going to support rich output.

Comment: is the output of `display()` HTML or text, if text you might include the required sub-module from the Jupyter module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although far from reproducing Jupyter's `display()`, [texttable](https://pypi.org/project/texttable/) library lets you print out stylish tables easily.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31891692)